# cordova-loader full example cordova meteor

Tags: cordova, meteor, loader

i have a meteor app and want to use it with cordova. Is there any real working full example? What i should to do to get it work? 
I tried this tutorial: https://github.com/andrewreedy/cordova-loader/wiki/Meteor---Cordova-Loader-Setup
But get this error if i try to install cordova-loader `mrt add cordova-loader`

> STDOUT:
>
> STDERR: Cloning into
>   '/home/xxx/.meteorite/source/andrewreedy/meteor-log'... remote:
>   Repository not found. fatal: repository
>   'https://github.com/andrewreedy/meteor-log.git/' not found

Some could help me out please ?

Answer (score 0):

this sample is perfectly work fine

```
https://github.com/zeroasterisk/meteor-cordova-geolocation-background
```